# Loading View From Nib doesn't initialize the outlets - Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, nib

hi i am currently trying to load dynamically a view from the NIB file
this is the code :

```
res1 = new View1();
var ptr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("View1",res1,null).ValueAt(0);
res1 = Runtime.GetNSObject(ptr) as View1;
```

res1 has a button inside.
 the button view is initialized and is inside the res1 view.

**but the outlet that i created in the interface builder on the button in NULL
how can initialize the outlets?**

Comment: Just declare button globally...

Comment: sorry i didn't understand you. can you elaborate on this?

Comment: In .h file write IBOutlet UIButton *yourBtn;  and  connect from file owner to button

Comment: i already have the outlets.. i've declared them but they are NULL after the creation of the view from the NIB. this is the problem.

Comment: disconnect and reconnect

Answer (score 1):

Try to use that way:

```
 //parameter 2 should be a controller.
 var ptr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("View1",this,null).ValueAt(0); 
 var res1 = new View1(ptr);
```

Because return type of the ValueAt method is IntPtr, and your view has a constructor take care that, it can add another view.

Comment: why the second parameter should be a controller ?

Comment: All nib files must have an Owner, I think it should be an UIViewController, which can manage your view. But if you want to use the same cells across multiple table views that reside in different Nib files, you can use NSObject. More detail in this link: http://software.tavlikos.com/2011/04/03/uitableviewcell-nib/